# Uso de namespace y extend con composer para multiple libreria, cual es la sintaxis?

Tags: php, poo, class

Estoy intentando replicar el contexto o metodología por el cual la libreria PHPMAILER implementa o usa en total 5 archivos y o mas de 5 clases:

no tengo un amplio conocimiento de herencia o POO a nivel de Clases pero he llegado a este punto:

**Clase principal de la libreria**

```
declare(strict_types=1);

namespace Pruebas\Pruebas;

class FooClass1 extends FooClass2
{
 /*para el ejemplo este no he colocado contenido, solo busco demostrar el acceso a metodos que estan en FooClass2*/
}
```

**Clase Secundaria de la librería para hacer validaciones**

```
declare(strict_types=1);

namespace Pruebas\Pruebas;

class FooClass2 
{
    public function verificar($dato)
    {
        echo 'hello World '.$dato;
    }
}
```

**index.php archivo de ejemplo**

```
use \Pruebas\Pruebas as Output;

require __DIR__ . '\..\vendor\autoload.php';

$output = new Output\Fooclass1();
$output->verificar('texto');
```

**OUTPUT**

> hello Wrold texto

el objetivo es Mediante la Instancia de la Clase principal tener accesos a las clases secundarias; en este ejemplo solo tengo una clase secundaria pero si requiero usar mas de 1, como seria la sintaxis del extend.

```
class A extend [B,C,D]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

no se puede; la manera de hacerlo seria:

**Clase principal de la libreria**

```
declare(strict_types=1);

namespace Pruebas\Pruebas;

class FooClass1 extends FooClass2
{

}
```

**Clase Secundaria de la libreria para hacer validaciones**

```
declare(strict_types=1);

namespace Pruebas\Pruebas;

class FooClass2 extends UltimaClass
{

}
```

**Clase terciaria de la libreria para hacer validaciones**

```
class UltimaClass
{
    public function verificar($dato)
    {
        echo 'hello World '.$dato;
    }
}
```